# Positioning element on top of flex item

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need help positioning elements on top of a flex item. I have 3 images in one row. At the left bottom corner of each image I want to add 2 elements, the green square and next to it the brand name. The brand name should have a top border the width the image. On the second image I would like to add a third element in the top-right corner. I've made [a simple jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rLkep36h/4/) to demonstrate where I am stuck. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldcfO.jpg) is what I need to do.

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/45/Red_High_Heel_Pumps.jpg">
      <span class="item-price group">&#36;145.99</span>
      <span class="item-brand-name group">Even</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/45/Red_High_Heel_Pumps.jpg" >
      <span class="item-price group">&#36;145.99</span>
      <span class="item-brand-name group">Even</span>
      <span class="on-sale">on sale</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/45/Red_High_Heel_Pumps.jpg">
      <span class="item-price group">&#36;145.99</span>
      <span class="item-brand-name group">Buffalo</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 270px;
}

.flex-container ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.flex-container li {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.flex-container .group {
  position: absolute;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transform: translate(20px, 200px)
}

.flex-container .item-price {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  color: white;
  background: rgb(87, 197, 160);
  height: 67px;
  width: 67px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.flex-container .item-brand-name {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  color: white;
  width: 250px;
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-container .on-sale {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  color: white;
  background: black;
  height: 67px;
  width: 67px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the `<li>` elements position to `relative` and the `.on-sale` class position to `absolute`. You are then able to position the `.on-sale` class anywhere you like relative to the `<li>` element.

Updated fiddle; https://jsfiddle.net/szd5fcvu/

Answer (score 1):

What about that?

I prefer always put flex rule on parent or make a table with divs.
I hope i helped you.

```css
.flex-container {
  display:flex;

}
img{
  width:300px;
  height:270px;
}
.flex-container ul{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.flex-container li{
display:flex;
position:relative;
justify-content: center;
align-items: flex-end;
float:left; 
width:300px;
height:270px;background:url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/45/Red_High_Heel_Pumps.jpg");
background-size:100%;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

 
 .flex-container .item-price{
 font-size: 0.8rem;
  color: white;
  background: rgb(87, 197, 160);
  height: 67px;
  width: 67px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  
}
   
 .flex-container .item-brand-name{
 font-size: 0.8rem;
  color: white;
  width:250px;
  background:red;
  float:left;
  height: 66px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  border-top:1px solid grey;

 
}
 
.flex-container .on-sale{
 font-size: 0.8rem;
  color: white;
  background: black;
  height: 67px;
  width: 67px;
  position:absolute;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  right:0;
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
   <ul>
    <li>
     <span class="item-price group">&#36;145.99</span>
     <span class="item-brand-name group">Even</span>
    </li>
    <li>
     <span class="item-price group">&#36;145.99</span>
     <span class="item-brand-name group">Even</span>
          <span class="on-sale">on sale</span>
    </li>
    <li>
     <span class="item-price group">&#36;145.99</span>
     <span class="item-brand-name group">Buffalo</span>
    </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use flexbox everywhere. I've removed a few lines of code and I positioned the on sale label `relative`. I hope it helps.

```css
.flex-container {
  display:flex;
}
img{
  width:300px;
  height:270px;
}
.flex-container ul{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.flex-container li{
  display:flex;
  position:relative;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.flex-container .group {
  position:absolute;
  justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
    transform:translate(20px, 200px)
    }
 
 .flex-container .item-price{
 font-size: 0.8rem;
  color: white;
  background: rgb(87, 197, 160);
  height: 67px;
  width: 67px;
  /*justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;*/
  text-align: center;
  line-height:67px;
  /*display: inline-flex;*/
}
   
 .flex-container .item-brand-name{
 font-size: 0.8rem;
  color: white;
  width:250px;
  border-top:1px solid grey;
  justify-content: center;
 
}
 
.flex-container .on-sale{
 font-size: 0.8rem;
  color: white;
  background: black;
  height: 67px;
  width: 67px;
  /*justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;*/
  text-align: center;
  /*display: inline-flex;*/
  line-height:67px;
  position:relative;
  right:90px;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
   <ul>
    <li>
     <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/45/Red_High_Heel_Pumps.jpg">
     <span class="item-price group">&#36;145.99</span>
     <span class="item-brand-name group">Even</span>
    </li>
    <li>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/45/Red_High_Heel_Pumps.jpg" >
     <span class="item-price group">&#36;145.99</span>
     <span class="item-brand-name group">Even</span>
          <span class="on-sale">on sale</span>
    </li>
    <li>
     <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/45/Red_High_Heel_Pumps.jpg">
     <span class="item-price group">&#36;145.99</span>
     <span class="item-brand-name group">Buffalo</span>
    </li>
   </ul>
      </div>
```